# How can I tab accross a ButtonBar component in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have a button bar inf flex along with several other input controls, I have set the tabIndex property for each control and all goes well until I tab to the ButtonBar.

The ButtonBar has 3 buttons but tabbing to it, only the first button gets focus, tab again and the focus goes back to the top control...

How can I make tabbing go through ALL buttons in a Flex Button bar? Is there a way to do this or do I need to create individual buttons for this?

This seems like a possible bug to me...

Answer (score 3):

The component is written so the user must press the left/right arrow keys when focus is within the bar to traverse the buttons--this is a fairly standard GUI behavior (you also see this in other places like radio button groups).  If you look into the [SDK source for ButtonBar](https://web.archive.org/web/20091214071345/http://opensource.adobe.com/svn/opensource/flex/sdk/tags/3.1.0.2710/frameworks/projects/framework/src/mx/controls/ButtonBar.as), you can see where they've explicitly disabled tab focus for each child button as it's created:

```
override protected function createNavItem(
                                        label:String,
                                        icon:Class = null):IFlexDisplayObject
    {
        var newButton:Button = Button(navItemFactory.newInstance());

        // Set tabEnabled to false so individual buttons don't get focus.
        newButton.focusEnabled = false;
    ...
```

If you really want to change this behavior, you can make a subclass to do it, something like this:

```
package {
    import mx.controls.Button;
    import mx.controls.ButtonBar;
    import mx.core.IFlexDisplayObject;

    public class FocusableButtonBar extends ButtonBar {
        public function FocusableButtonBar()
        {
            super();
            this.focusEnabled = false;
        }

        override protected function createNavItem(
                    label:String, icon:Class=null):IFlexDisplayObject
        {
            var btn:Button = Button(super.createNavItem(label, icon));
            btn.focusEnabled = true;
            return btn;
        }
    }
}
```